# Why is sam sync --watch command not automatically updating?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

The command
`sam sync --watch --stack-name sam-app --region us-east-1` 
is not working for me.

When I execute the sam synch --watch command, the first run it will update code as expected. But the --watch command should also detect local code changes and update the AWS Stack. The automatic update is not working for me. I followed the instructions from [official aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/accelerate-getting-started.html)

Output:

```
sam sync --watch --stack-name sam-app --region=us-e
ast-1

The SAM CLI will use the AWS Lambda, Amazon API Gateway, and AWS StepFunctions APIs to upload your code without
performing a CloudFormation deployment. This will cause drift in your CloudFormation stack.
**The sync command should only be used against a development stack**.

Queued infra sync. Waiting for in progress code syncs to complete...
Starting infra sync.
Manifest is not changed for (HelloWorldFunction), running incremental build
Building codeuri: /mnt/c/Users/Topicus/Documents/AWS SAM workshop/sam-accelerate-test/sam-tutorial/hello_world runtime: python3.9 metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: HelloWorldFunction
Running PythonPipBuilder:CopySource

Build Succeeded

Successfully packaged artifacts and wrote output template to file /tmp/tmpbib_f3ku.
Execute the following command to deploy the packaged template
sam deploy --template-file /tmp/tmpbib_f3ku --stack-name <YOUR STACK NAME>


        Deploying with following values
        ===============================
        Stack name                   : sam-app
        Region                       : us-east-1
        Disable rollback             : False
        Deployment s3 bucket         : aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-ghvaajc0i25f
        Capabilities                 : ["CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM", "CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"]
        Parameter overrides          : {}
        Signing Profiles             : null

Initiating deployment
=====================

2023-02-13 14:27:45 - Waiting for stack create/update to complete

CloudFormation events from stack operations (refresh every 0.5 seconds)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceStatus           ResourceType             LogicalResourceId        ResourceStatusReason
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::CloudFormation::S   sam-app                  Transformation
                         tack                                              succeeded
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::IAM::Role           HelloWorldFunctionRole   -

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::CloudFormation::S   AwsSamAutoDependencyLa   -

                         tack                     yerNestedStack

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::ResourceGroups::G   ApplicationResourceGro   -

                         roup                     up

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::IAM::Role           HelloWorldFunctionRole   Resource creation
                                                                           Initiated
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::CloudFormation::S   AwsSamAutoDependencyLa   Resource creation
                         tack                     yerNestedStack           Initiated
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::ResourceGroups::G   ApplicationResourceGro   Resource creation
                         roup                     up                       Initiated
CREATE_COMPLETE          AWS::ResourceGroups::G   ApplicationResourceGro   -

                         roup                     up

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::ApplicationInsigh   ApplicationInsightsMon   -

                         ts::Application          itoring

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::ApplicationInsigh   ApplicationInsightsMon   Resource creation
                         ts::Application          itoring                  Initiated
CREATE_COMPLETE          AWS::IAM::Role           HelloWorldFunctionRole   -

CREATE_COMPLETE          AWS::CloudFormation::S   AwsSamAutoDependencyLa   -

                         tack                     yerNestedStack

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::Lambda::Function    HelloWorldFunction       -

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::Lambda::Function    HelloWorldFunction       Resource creation
                                                                           Initiated
CREATE_COMPLETE          AWS::Lambda::Function    HelloWorldFunction       -

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::ApiGateway::RestA   ServerlessRestApi        -

                         pi

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::ApiGateway::RestA   ServerlessRestApi        Resource creation
                         pi                                                Initiated
CREATE_COMPLETE          AWS::ApiGateway::RestA   ServerlessRestApi        -

                         pi

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::ApiGateway::Deplo   ServerlessRestApiDeplo   -

                         yment                    yment47fc2d5f9d

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::Lambda::Permissio   HelloWorldFunctionHell   -

                         n                        oWorldPermissionProd

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::Lambda::Permissio   HelloWorldFunctionHell   Resource creation
                         n                        oWorldPermissionProd     Initiated
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::ApiGateway::Deplo   ServerlessRestApiDeplo   Resource creation
                         yment                    yment47fc2d5f9d          Initiated
CREATE_COMPLETE          AWS::ApiGateway::Deplo   ServerlessRestApiDeplo   -

                         yment                    yment47fc2d5f9d

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::ApiGateway::Stage   ServerlessRestApiProdS   -

                                                  tage

CREATE_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::ApiGateway::Stage   ServerlessRestApiProdS   Resource creation
                                                  tage                     Initiated
CREATE_COMPLETE          AWS::ApiGateway::Stage   ServerlessRestApiProdS   -

                                                  tage

CREATE_COMPLETE          AWS::Lambda::Permissio   HelloWorldFunctionHell   -

                         n                        oWorldPermissionProd

CREATE_COMPLETE          AWS::ApplicationInsigh   ApplicationInsightsMon   -

                         ts::Application          itoring

CREATE_COMPLETE          AWS::CloudFormation::S   sam-app                  -

                         tack

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CloudFormation outputs from deployed stack
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Outputs

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Key                 HelloWorldFunctionIamRole

Description         Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function

Value               arn:aws:iam::492917996281:role/sam-app-HelloWorldFunctionRole-19A7FE07PFT9I

Key                 HelloWorldApi

Description         API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function
Value               https://tzhcv2u047.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/

Key                 HelloWorldFunction

Description         Hello World Lambda Function ARN

Value               arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:492917996281:function:sam-app-

HelloWorldFunction-0Z7T5JWyTwbt

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Stack creation succeeded. Sync infra completed.

Infra sync completed.
CodeTrigger not created as CodeUri or DefinitionUri is missing for ServerlessRestApi.
```

Edit: also tried to with `sam sync --stack-name sam-app --code --resource-id HelloWorldFunction --resource-id HelloWorldLayer --region us-east-1 --watch`. Same result, no automatic update.
This does work: `sam sync --stack-name sam-app --code --resource-id HelloWorldFunction --resource-id HelloWorldLayer --region us-east-1`, but it's not automatic..

Comment: Is SAM ignoring code changes to your SAM template?  Lambda code?

Comment: Both, the --watch command doesn't do anything. I suspect it has something to do with me using wsl for Windows.